# Prove that sets $A$ and $B$ are disjoint iff $A \cup B = A \bigtriangleup B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm studying for my exam and I came up with this little proof, but I'm wary because the professor took a much longer approach. Am I right in saying that a symmetric difference is the same as the difference between a union and an intersection? Thanks in advance.

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

This means $A \cap B = \varnothing$

Since $A \bigtriangleup B$ is the set of all elements that belong to $A$ or $B$ but not to both, 
$$A \bigtriangleup B = A \cup B - A \cap B$$

$A \cap B = \varnothing$, therefore $A \bigtriangleup B = A \cup B$.

Comment: This is half of the proof. You are not done. And if the symmetric difference was defined differently (for instance, as $(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$), then you still need to prove that it is union minus intersection.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo what would be the second half?

Answer (score 4):

$A \Delta B=(A-B)\cup(B-A)$
$=(A\cap B^C)\cup(B\cap A^C)$
$=(A\cup B)\cap(A^C\cup B^C)$
$=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cap B)^C=(A\cup B)-(A\cap B)$

Answer (score 0):

You can just see the proprieties of definition of symmetrical difference
If $A\cap B= \emptyset$ then $A\backslash B = A$ and $B\backslash A=B$, then you can say that the definition of symmetrical difference is $A\bigtriangleup B = (A\backslash B) \cup (B\backslash A)$ there for the initial condition you can say  $A\bigtriangleup B = A\cup B$

The thing the professor might do it longer than yours is because of the arguments, but in essence its the same, but be sure to argument every set its a big deal in mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}\text{#2}\unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
\newcommand{\empty}{\varnothing}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathbin \triangle}
$This is not a direct answer to your question, but an alternative proof in a different style.

Here is (the beginning of) a 'logical' way to prove your
$$
\tag 0
A \cap B = \empty \;\equiv\; A \cup B = A \diff B
$$
i.e., by using the definitions to go to the element level, and using the laws of logic to simplify and complete the proof.

We will use the following not-too-well-known definition of $\;\diff\;$: for all $\;x\;$,
$$
\tag 1
x \in A \diff B \;\equiv\; x \in A \not\equiv x \in B
$$
and we use the fact that $\;\equiv\;$ and $\;\not\equiv\;$ are symmetric, associative, and even mutually associative.

---

We start at the most complex side of $\ref 0$, and calculate

$$\calc
A \cup B = A \diff B
\calcop\equiv{set extensionality, definition of $\;\cup\;$, definition $\ref 1$ of $\;\diff\;$}
\langle \forall x :: x \in A \lor x \in B \;\equiv\; x \in A \not\equiv x \in B \rangle
\calcop\equiv{logic: extract $\;\lnot\;$ -- to prepare for $\ref 2$, see below}
\langle \forall x :: \lnot (x \in A \lor x \in B \;\equiv\; x \in A \;\equiv\; x \in B) \rangle
\calcop\equiv{...}
\endcalc$$

---

Now finish it yourself, by applying the 'golden rule'
$$
\tag 2
P \;\equiv\; Q \;\equiv\; P \lor Q \;\equiv\; P \land Q
$$
and the definitions of $\;\cap\;$ and $\;\empty\;$ to reach the left hand side of $\ref 0$.