# Prove that: A and B are disjoint sets → AΔB = A∪B

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I´m trying to prove that using the definitions for [Δ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) and [∪](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) and [=](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equality_(mathematics)), but nothing comes to my mind! Thanks.

Comment: Hint. You need to use the definition of "disjoint" and see how that affects the calculation of $\Delta$.

Comment: Hint: use (or prove, first) that $A \Delta B = (A \cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)\,$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that sets $A$ and $B$ are disjoint iff $A \cup B = A \bigtriangleup B$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052618/prove-that-sets-a-and-b-are-disjoint-iff-a-cup-b-a-bigtriangleup-b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $$A\Delta B := (A-B)\cup(B-A)$$

If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint what repens with $A-B$? This symbol means that 'every element that $A$ has but $B$ doesn't'. If they are disjoint no element of $B$ is in $A$ and vice-versa.

$$A-B := A\cap B^c $$

Where $B^c$ is the complement of $B$. If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint you have that $A \cap B = \varnothing $ so $A \cap B^c = A$. In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2195563/symmetric-difference-using-venn-diagrams-discrete-math/2195686#2195686) there is a good look in what a symmetric difference is and an important relation that satisfies.